# change format of bootstrap datetimepicker on event

Tags: event-handling, format, onchange, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I know how to change a datetimepicker date format, but I cant find a way to reformat it once its been initialized. I want the format to change if certain checkbox is checked.

This is what I tried:

```
    if ($('#dateAndTime').is(':checked')) {
      defaultFrom = moment().subtract(1, 'hours').subtract(currentSecond, 'seconds');
      defaultFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm';
    } else {
      defaultFrom = moment().subtract(7, 'days').subtract(currentSecond, 'seconds');
      defaultFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH';
    }
```

It makes the defaultFrom changes, but not the defaultFormat changes.
This is how the datetimepicker looks:

```
    // Configure the from datetime date pickers
    $('#dateTimePickerFrom').datetimepicker({
      format: defaultFormat,
      minDate: moment().subtract(90, 'days'),
      defaultDate: defaultFrom
    }).on('dp.change', function(e) {
      if (!validDateTimeRange()) {
        $('#ok-button').attr('disabled', true);
      } else {
        $('#ok-button').removeAttr('disabled');
      }

    });
```

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for the same thing. You asked it before a month, there are no answers here. Did find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by destroying `datetimepicker` on checkbox change event and then reattaching it.

I have included my code below.

What I did - when All Day Event checkbox(`#eventAllDay`) is checked, display only `date` selection in Event Start Date(`#eventStartDate`) and Event End Date(`#eventEndDate). And if it is unchecked, display`datetime` selection.

```js
 $(document).on('change', '#eventAllDay', function(e, data) {

   if ($('#eventStartDate').data('DateTimePicker') != undefined) {
     $('#eventStartDate').data('DateTimePicker').destroy();
     $('#eventEndDate').data('DateTimePicker').destroy();
   }

   if ($('#eventAllDay').is(':checked')) {

     $('#eventStartDate').datetimepicker({
       useCurrent: true,
       showClose: true,
       format: 'L'
     });
     $('#eventEndDate').datetimepicker({
       useCurrent: true,
       showClose: true,
       format: 'L'
     });
     return;

   } else {


     $('#eventStartDate').datetimepicker({
       useCurrent: true,
       showClose: true,
       format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
     });
     $('#eventEndDate').datetimepicker({
       useCurrent: true,
       showClose: true,
       format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
     });
     return;

   }
 });
```

Thanks.